# Is it possible to put references without an author at the end of the bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib

In my `.bib`-file I have a a reference to an online ressource like this:

```
@Misc{RealSense,
  title        = {{Intel RealSense} Product homepage},
  howpublished = {\url{https://www.intelrealsense.com/}},
  note         = {Accessed: 2020-03-05},
}
```

Referencing it will result it in appearing on first position in my bibliography, because it's sorted alphabeticall after the first authors' last name by default and apparently no author means first position. I am obligated to use documentclass `scrbook` and `natbib`-package. So you can assume a document like this:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url}

\bibliographystyle{abbrv}

\begin{document}
abc\cite{RealSense}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{bib/bibliography}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to make this reference appear at the end of the bibliography?

Comment: Which bibliography style do you employ? (The code you posted above cannot be compiled successfully without a `\bibliographystyle` directive.)

Comment: @Mico For me it somehow compiled. But I edited the question to include the bibliography style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that you use the `abbrv` bibliography style along with the `natbib` citation management package is important, as it permits the following approach to meeting your formatting requirement. I suggest you create the following `key` field and insert it in entries that lack `author` and `editor` fields:

```
    key = {ZZZZZ},
```

The `abbrv` bibliography style is programmed to sort the bibliographic entries alphabetically by authors' surnames. If an entry lacks an `author` or `editor` field, `abbrv` falls back on the `key` field -- for sorting purposes. (`abbrv` doesn't actually print out the contents of the `key` field.) Since `ZZZZZ` (hopefully...) has a lower alphabetic sorting priority than any real surname, the entry gets placed *last* in the sorting queue -- exactly what you want, isn't it?

If you have several entries that lack `author` and `editor` fields, just use `key` values such as `ZZZZZ1`, `ZZZZZ2`, `ZZZZZ3`, etc.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{bibliography.bib}
@Misc{RealSense,
  key          = {ZZZZZ},
  title        = {{Intel RealSense} Product homepage},
  howpublished = {\url{https://www.intelrealsense.com/}},
  note         = {Accessed: 2020-03-05},
}
@misc{aa,author="Anne Author",title="XYZ",year=3001}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\usepackage{xurl}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks a lot! And it's so much easier and cleaner than I would have expected... And also: I learned how to include a bibliography in an MWE properly. Thanks for that one, too ;)

Comment: @Max - You're most welcome!